# Winform let user resize the form manually on runti

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, controls

I checked with many stackoverflow answer and msdn but so far, I couldn't find a solution which allow the user to resize my form on runtime. Am I missing something? I attempted Form.Minsize and Maxsize but still not allow me to do what I want.

Comment: [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: already set it to sizable, cant change the form still

Comment: Not possible to tell without the form designer part. Remember to reset MinSize and MaxSize to zero if you have changed them.

Comment: Also ensure that the properties AutoSize = false and AutoSizeMode = GrowOnly

Comment: Bernd Linde, that did the trick. Can you post ur answer so I can make it answer for the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments by @Steve and myself:

The following properties can all prevent the manual resizing of a form:

- [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) (Should be either Sizable or FixedSizableWindow)
- [MinimumSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize(v=vs.110).aspx) and [MaximumSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize(v=vs.110).aspx) (Reset both to 0, won't prevent resizing, just resizing past a certain point.)
- [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) (Set to False) and [AutoSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) (Set to GrowOnly)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to mean that if you have any elements that appear in a certain state the outer form doesn't grow to make room for them.